# Remove Image associated with button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am developing an app where someone can select multiple Images from a gallery. I've appended a button with every image which calls the function onclick. How can I remove the image appended with button onclick ?

```
<div id="images">
    <img src="www.xyz.com/qwert.jpg" class="hi">
    <input type="button" class="multiple">
    <img src="www.xyz.com/qwerty.jpg" class="hi">
    <input type="button" class="multiple">
    <img src="www.xyz.com/qwertww.jpg" class="hi">
    <input type="button" class="multiple">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
$(".multiple").click(function () {
  $(this).prev("img").remove();
});
```

**Snippet**

```js
$(function () {
  $(".multiple").click(function () {
    $(this).prev("img").remove();
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="images">
  <img src="www.xyz.com/qwert.jpg" class="hi">
  <input type="button" class="multiple">
  <img src="www.xyz.com/qwerty.jpg" class="hi">
  <input type="button" class="multiple">
  <img src="www.xyz.com/qwertww.jpg" class="hi">
  <input type="button" class="multiple">
</div>
```

Comment: How can I hide/remove button after image gets deleted ?

Comment: Currently it is removing it. What exactly you wanna do @NehilMistry?

Comment: Done. I was asking to remove button after image gets deleted. 
`$(this).remove;`

Comment: Yup... `$(this).remove()`

Comment: @PraveenKumar better answer.